# Angular2: Dynamically create view selector based on model property?

Tags: javascript, templates, angular, typescript, typescript2.0

I've been a C/C++ coder for a long time, but am new to Angular2 and TypeScript. I have a TypeScript class (call it `Node`) which has a `type: string` property that specifies what sort of node it is. (The data comes as JSON from a server, and is basically being parsed out as a syntax tree.)

What I'm doing now in the view template in order to choose the view for each `Node` object is using an `ngSwitch` to check the value of `node.type`, and then inserting the appropriate selector using `ngSwitchCase` for each possible case, e.g.:

```
<div [ngSwitch]="node.type">
    <node-type-a-view *ngSwitchCase="'a'" [(node)]="node"></node-type-a-view>
    <node-type-b-view *ngSwitchCase="'b'" [(node)]="node"></node-type-a-view>
    <node-type-c-view *ngSwitchCase="'c'" [(node)]="node"></node-type-a-view>
    <div class="debug" *ngSwitchDefault>
        TODO: View for type "{{node.type}}" is missing
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that there are over a hundred different node types, and so this is going to be very unwieldy, very quickly.
What I'd *like* to do is something like this (but obviously this doesn't work in Angular2):

```
<node-type-{{node.type}}-view [(node)]="node"></node-type-{{node.type}}-view>
```

Or, using an attribute selector:

```
<div node-type-{{node.type}}-view [(node)]="node"></div>
```

Is there any functionality that comes close to what I'm looking for? I don't need to dynamically create the `node-type-*-view` views themselves, just the template that references them.

Also, apologies if I'm getting this architecture completely wrong. I'm still wrapping my head around the way Angular2 does things!

Thanks for any assistance you can give!